# what do you call the accordion box in fixed position like a chat box?

Tags: jquery, accordion, fixed, livechat

what do you call something like a chatbox which when u click it pop ups upward and show a content like a chat box??

i cant seem to find the term to search for that.. all i know is an accordion box which similar to that..

similar to this one

http://jordie.org/faq/wordpress/?page_id=31 the email or social links

if you could also provide some existing examples or tutorials that would be great :D

Comment: @Hushme thanks for the reply, do you know some examples?

Comment: use a simple accordion menu like tabify in a popup it will work

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome plugin to do that. Just navigate into this http://www.sunarlim.com/2010/03/contactable-jquery-plugin-on-the-right-side-of-page/

Comment: nice link but i want a bottom right one with added tabs, one for contact and one for a chat box?? do u have any ideas, thanks for the answer :)